# pandas calculated field by comparing other fields and dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have two dataframes. the first one looks like this:

```
id, orderdate, orderid, amount,camp1, camp2, camp3
1   2020-01-01  100      100       1    0       0
2   2020-02-01  120      200       1    0       1
3   2019-12-01  130      500       0    1       0
4   2019-11-01  150      750       0    1       0
5   2020-01-01  160      1000      1    1       1
```

`camp1, camp2, camp3` parts show if the customer attended to a campaign.

and the campaigns have a period dictionary such that

```
camp_periods = {'camp1': 
                        [datetime.strptime('2019-04-08', '%Y-%m-%d'), datetime.strptime('2019-06-06', '%Y-%m-%d')],
                'camp2':
                        [datetime.strptime('2019-09-15', '%Y-%m-%d'), datetime.strptime('2019-09-28', '%Y-%m-%d')],
                'camp3':
                        [datetime.strptime('2019-11-15', '%Y-%m-%d'), datetime.strptime('2019-12-28', '%Y-%m-%d')]
                 }
```

I would like to create a table giving the number of orders and total of `order amounts` per customer, if the `orderdate` is between the campaign periods in the `camp_periods` dictionary and if the customer attended to that campaign.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood very well your question, I guess when you say the number of orders and total of `order amounts` you want to get the first `n` number of orders that are under or equal with a given total `order amounts`, here is my approach:

data example:

[image]

```
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce


number_orders = 2
total_order_amounts = 3000
```

> orderdate is between the campaign periods in the camp_periods
>   dictionary and if the customer attended to that campaign

```
cond = [(df[k].astype('bool') & df['orderdate'].between(*v)) for k, v in camp_periods.items()]
cond = reduce(or_, cond)
df_cond = df[cond]
df_final = df_cond[df_cond['amount'].cumsum() <= total_order_amounts].head(number_orders)

df_final
```

output:

[image]